# 行为艺术：translation?

Tags: translation

**21 Century Dictionary**

> behavioural art
>
> 行为艺术

I don't know what on earth *behavioural art* is, it sounds like a direct translation from Chinese, if anything. A *bing* search didn't show up anything on behavioural art either, google being blocked over here and all.

My best guess is that it's the same as performance art but I can't find any evidence to support this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The proper translation is [performance art](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Performance_art)**, because that's what the Chinese name `行为艺术` was coined for. Although the *literal* meaning of the Chinese name is not quite the same as that of the English name, they refer to the same thing, and therefore should be taken as each others translation: as in fact, they are.

For evidence I'll cite the English and Chinese references to the `行為藝術` / Performance Art of [Taiwanese artist Lee Ming Sheng.](http://wiki.avat-art.org/mediawiki/index.php/%E6%9D%8E%E9%8A%98%E7%9B%9B)

**[Chinese Reference:](http://www.mlsh.mlc.edu.tw/mediafile/741/news/19/2012-11/2012-11-12-9-52-32-nf1.pdf)**

[image: chinese]

**[English Reference:](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0415602939)**

[image: english]

Answer (score 1):

A possible translation for 行为艺术 should be "the arts of behaving" or "etiquette" in English. Here 艺术 means arts of a knowledge, for example, martial arts.

Comment: Is that even a *thing* in English?

Comment: I think it is a knowledge, like a course in high school or college, isn't it? Where did you get this term?

Comment: Were you reading about behaviorism?

Comment: @user3306356 while there actually are etiquette schools in western society (e.g. [The Etiquette School of New York](http://etiquette-ny.com/),) I really do not think this term is referencing such a thing ChineseHulu.com. Semaphore's answer sounds much more correct.

Comment: I agree. Sorry will do more research next time.